# How to add images to Pythonista's ui designer

Tags: python, pythonista

I have been fooling around with python and Pythonista 2.5 on iOS. I currently am far too inexperienced to create good UIs in scripts and need some help using the designer in Pythonista. I currently wish to add an image asset, yet I am only able to use stock images provided, is there any folder path I can follow to add my images to that list, or is there another simple way of doing it?

Keep in mind I have little experience and thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4):

You can store the images files in any folder. A simple way to copy external images would be to first copy it in clipboard (may be from photos) and then save it as png file by running the following script.
(Custom images are currently not supported in the UI editor, You have to load them via code.
 https://forum.omz-software.com/topic/3668/images-in-ui-designer
But you can use the [+] button in the code editor (at the top) to view bundled images/textures. (images in the current directory are also shown.)
 https://forum.omz-software.com/topic/3760/itunes-file-sharing )

```
import clipboard

image = clipboard.get_image()
image.show()
image.save('img1.png')
```

You can also use dropbox or appex scripts to store images.